# calling another function in the default function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react and I created a auth file to store all of my api request related to authentication purposes. I have inside a default function signin with a signin request, and I also want to store a signup request in the same file. I believe I am doing something wrong as it is not rendering properly.

here is my code:

```
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';

export const signin = async(data)=>{
const config = {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
};

const  response = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/auth/signin', data, config);
return response;
};


const signup = async(data)=>{
const config = {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
};

const  rep = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/auth/signup', data, config);
return rep;
};

export default signin;
```

Comment: your can remove the `export default signin;` and instead of importing your module like `import sth from 'somewhere'` import it like `import {someFunction} from 'somewhere'`

Answer (score 0):

Like @saeed stated in his comment, you could export both signin and signup normally and import them somewhere else using `import {signin, signup} from 'access'`.

```js
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export const signin = async (data) => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  };

  const response = await axios.post(
    'http://localhost:5000/api/auth/signin',
    data,
    config,
  );
  return response;
};

export const signup = async (data) => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  };

  const rep = await axios.post(
    'http://localhost:5000/api/auth/signup',
    data,
    config,
  );
  return rep;
};
```

And to import the functions:

```js
import {signin, signup} from 'somefile'
```